# Load testing tool URL encoding system

Tags: url, escaping, load-testing

I have a load testing tool (Borland's SilkPerformer) that is encoding `/` character as `\x252f`. Can anyone please tell me what encoding system the tool might be using?

Answer (score 0):

Two different escape sequences have been combined:

- a C string hexadecimal escape sequence.
- an URL-encoding scheme (percent encoding).

See this little diagram:

```
   +--------->  C escape in hexadecimal notation
   :  +------>  hexadecimal number, ASCII for '%'
   :  :  +--->  hexadecimal number, ASCII for '/'
  \x 25 2f
```

Explained step for step:

1. `\` starts a C string escape sequence.
2. `x` is an escape in hexadecimal notation. Two hex digits are expected to follow.
3. `25` is `%` in ASCII, see [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/).
4. `%` starts an URL encode, also called [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Two hex digits are expected to follow.
5. `2f` is the slash character (`/`) in ASCII.
6. The slash is the result.

Now I don't know why your software chooses to encode the slash character in such a weird way. Slash characters in urls need to be url encoded if they don't denote directory separators (the same thing the backslash does for Windows). So you will often find the slash character being encoded as `%2f`. That's normal. But I find it weird and a bit suspicious that the percent character is additionally encoded as a hexadecimal escape sequence for C strings.

Comment: thx nalply for your help....actually what's happening is that i am getting the string "x252f" in the source of a web page. My tool then prepares a script in which 'x252f' is encoded as '/'. When i run the script, the tool again encodes that '/' but this time it encodes it to %2f. So eventually 'x252f' gets encoded to '%2f'. Now what i want to know is that is there any way through which i can directly encode 'x252f' to '%2f' rather than the tool doing it. I mean is there any encoding system or some function or piece of code that i can use to achieve this??

Comment: It depends on which programming language you are using. In JavaScript you can use the encodeURI() function. PHP has the rawurlencode() function and ASP has the Server.URLEncode() function. (Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Comment: Note, however that the urlencode functions only encode `/` to `%2f` and don't understand `\x252f` or `x252f`.